# Adding multiple policies to S3 with CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have a bucket I am creating with CDK

```
const bucket =  new Bucket(scope, "MyS3Bucket", {
    bucketName: Fn.sub("mys3bucket"),
    blockPublicAccess: {
      blockPublicAcls: true,
      blockPublicPolicy: true,
      ignorePublicAcls: true,
      restrictPublicBuckets: true,
    },
    encryption: BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
    removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  });
```

currently I am doing this.

```
 const psList = new PolicyStatement({// policy stuff});
 const psDeny = new PolicyStatement({ // policy stuff});
 const psAllow = new PolicyStatement({// policy stuff});
```

And adding them individually

```
bucket.addToResourcePolicy(psList);
bucket.addToResourcePolicy(psDeny);
bucket.addToResourcePolicy(psAllow);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, seems like there could be added directly to the bucket closure?